# Why does alignat not work here?

Tags: align, alignment, alignat

How can I align these?  I tried alignat but somehow it doesn't work here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
|x|&= 
\begin{cases}
-x  &   && x \leq 0\\
x  &   && x \geq 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
f_k &= k + 3  && \text{ k} \geq 0 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see no logical reason to align them. In fact, if you do, you will give the impression that there is, and perhaps trick some readers.

Comment: @mickep probably you're right. I just wanted to make it nicer.

Comment: there is no alignment specified (the `cases` is a "black box" and `&` inside do not correspond to `&` outside. Also why k in text mode???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  you're right. `k` should not in text. I also tried this but it doesn't work either. ```\begin{cases}
&-x  &  &&  x \leq 0\\
&x  &   && x \geq 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
&f_k &= k + 3  && \text{ k} \geq 0 ```

Comment: @hana never ignore error messages!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not really, I checked the error and also searched for alignat tutorial but saw no document except the discussion from stackexchange and some other forums.

Comment: you certainly did not mention in your question that you got an error. It isn't really worth asking why you get any particular alignment after an error. If you scroll past an error tex tries to recover enough to check more of the document but does not try to make sensible output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I probably need a course to learn instead of doing random things like this.

Comment: To add to @mickep comment: the condition on `f_k` of a very different nature than those in the `cases` environment; I'd even avoid accidental alignment. You may add parentheses around `k\geq0`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this layout, obtained with `\mathrlap`, from `mathtools`?

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
    |x|&=
    \mathrlap{\begin{cases}
    -x & x \leq 0\\
    x & x \geq 0
    \end{cases}} \\[0.5ex]
    f_k &= k + 3\mathrlap{,} &\quad & k \geq 0
    \end{alignat}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your document produces

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> $\hfil $$\endtemplate
```

As `cases` only allows one `&` per row.

After any error the PDF is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid, and if asking here it is better to show the error rather than the PDF.

See how the conditions are forced to spurious new lines as TeX recovers from the error

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
|x|&= 
\begin{cases}
-x  &  x \leq 0\\
x  &  x \geq 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
f_k &= k + 3  \quad k \geq 0 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about something like this too but then I also thought manually doing like this probably leaves some small misalignment so I decided to try align.

Comment: @hana yes I added `\quad` as a more or less arbitrary spacer, it's a bit unfortunate that it almost looks aligned, that's just how it fell out